# Change table row layout with css

Tags: css, responsive-design, couch-cms

I've got a table

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A1</td>
      <td>Cell A2</td>
      <td>Cell A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell B1</td>
      <td>Cell B2</td>
      <td>Cell B3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need to do is display the **whole table** as a **single column** using **CSS**

The output should be:

```
 +---------+
 | Cell A1 |
 +---------+
 | Cell A2 |
 +---------+
 | Cell A3 |
 +---------+
 | Cell B1 |
 +---------+
 | Cell B2 |
 +---------+
 | Cell B3 |
 +---------+
```

The reason behind this is that every table cell is very wide and the table is generated by CouchCMS in its admin panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a little bit of CSS to display as `block` each element in the table, and hide your `thead`:

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  display: block;
}

thead {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A1</td>
      <td>Cell A2</td>
      <td>Cell A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell B1</td>
      <td>Cell B2</td>
      <td>Cell B3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/k8pojm31/

Answer (score 1):

Try this set of css rules

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody,
thead,tr {
  display: block;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 4px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell A1</td>
      <td>Cell A2</td>
      <td>Cell A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell B1</td>
      <td>Cell B2</td>
      <td>Cell B3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a single column, then don't use multiple `<th>`. Use a single `<th>` tag if you want column heading. If you don't want column heading, then try this code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
span{
color:#019ac8;

}
table{
border:1px dotted #000;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Cell</span> A1</td></tr>
      <tr><td><span>Cell</span> A2</td></tr>
      <tr><td><span>Cell</span> A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Cell</span> B1</td></tr>
      <tr><td><span>Cell</span> B2</td></tr>
     </tr> <td><span>Cell</span> B3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```